# В битрикс не работает $APPLICATION->ShowHead()

Tags: javascript, битрикс

В `head` прописан `$APPLICATION->ShowHead()`, но не подключает библиотеки для неавторизованных пользователей, зато для админа - все ок. 
В консоли ошибки:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined"
>   "и Uncaught ReferenceError: BX is not defined

В чем может быть дело? Куда копать?

Comment: Звучит как неподклюяенное ядро CJSCore::Init() добавьте в head

Comment: Пробовал отдельно подключать - не помогает, скрипты не добавляются, под админом все работает

Comment: Значит где-то прописано условие IsAdmin() проверьте init.php.

Comment: Bingo! Спасибо, добрый человек!